# Swift CGRectMake Center button

Tags: swift, button

I'm programming a button to my `swift` spriest project.
but the location of the button is messing up.
I wan it to be in the middel but it goes some random place.

```
let button = UIButton(type: .System) // let preferred over var here
button.frame = CGRectMake(self.frame.width / 2, self.frame.height / 2, 100, 50)
print(self.frame.height / 2)
button.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
button.setTitle("Button", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
self.view!.addSubview(button)
```

I don't know why it does it with a `CGPoint` it works but i can't use a `CGPoint` here.

Comment: looks like you're missing the frame starting point. Shouldn't it be CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.x + self.frame.width / 2 ...  ?

Comment: Hmm IDK let me try.

Comment: What is self.frame.origin what does it show?

Comment: try to use swift syntax where possible button.frame = CGRect(x: self.frame.width / 2, y: self.frame.height / 2, width: 100, height: 50)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this...

```
button.frame = CGRectMake(
    self.view.center.x - (WidthOfButton / 2), 
    self.view.center.y - (HeightOfButton / 2), 
    WidthOfButton, 
    HeightOfButton)
```

Comment: Thanks Mate This Worked!

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
let button = UIButton(type: .System) // let preferred over var here
    button.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.width / 2-(widthOfButton/2), self.view.frame.height / 2-(HeightOfButton/2), 100, 50)
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    button.setTitle("Button", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    self.view!.addSubview(button)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried...?

```
button.frame = CGRectMake((self.frame.width-100) / 2, (self.frame.height - 50)/ 2, 100, 50)
```

also update this in your `viewWillAppear` method

Comment: `self.frame.size.width`  and `self.frame.size.height` maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Try this!!!!

```
button.frame = CGRectMake((self.view.frame.width - 100) / 2, (self.view.frame.height - 50) / 2, 100, 50)
```

Comment: Value of type 'GameScene' has no member 'center'